We know that people can hear whether the water is hot or cold from the act of pouring, but have we ever considered the shape and material of the cup?
We know that one can hear whether water is hot or cold from the act of pouring, which is related to the viscosity of the water, the column of air inside the container, and the overall vibration of the container and the water. Has consideration been given to the choice of material and shape of the cup? For example, which style and material of cup has the most significant effect on this sound amplification; for example, glass or metal cup; thin or thick walls, etc.

To answer this will require a lot of additional, perhaps more specific, information. Also, please ask one question at a time.

To a large degree the material of the cup does not matter, as long as it is solid and rigid (plastic cups may be different). The reason is that the sound comes from  bubbles and the air inside vibrating, powered by the fluid flow. So the cup doesn't participate other than as a boundary, and the material likely has little effect unless it somehow affects the flow (very smooth or rough surfaces, for example).
So the main way a cup changes the sound is by size and shape (will affect the resonant frequencies).
Addendum: in (Bi, Su, Zhou 2024) they note that initially there may be a tinkling sound due to vibrations in the material of the cup, dependent on its natural resonant frequency. So that would depend on material, size, thickness etc.

The shape and material of the cup will affect the resonant frequency of the cup. Cups or glasses with a stem (wine glass) are preferred since the stem reduces vibration damping from contact with a table.
A Glass Harp or "Singing Wine Glasses" utilize this effect.
This paper provides a nice analysis:
https://www.academia.edu/50849810/Resonance_Frequency_of_a_Singing_Wine_Glass
